# Autotools: using -D with variable works for all but one compile (C programming)

Tags: c, makefile, autotools, automake

I am in the process of converting old autotools setup with a handwritten `Makefile.in` (and of-course a `configure.in`) to the latest (`Makefile.am` and `configure.ac`). Up to now things were looking fine, but I ran into something I cannot find the answer for in other questions.

I added a define in `Makefile.am` that is included in the compile of all c-modules I indicated in `_SOURCES` but one. I see absolutely no difference between the c-sources, except that the one where the define is not included in the compile is the main of the program.

Below the code for `Makefile.am` (relevant part):

```
bin_PROGRAMS = wpe we 
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libxwpe-x11.la libxwpe-term.la
libxwpe_x11_la_SOURCES = we_xterm.c WeXterm.c
libxwpe_x11_la_CPPFLAGS = -DLIBRARY_DIR=\"@libdir@/xwpe\"
libxwpe_term_la_SOURCES = we_term.c
libxwpe_term_la_CPPFLAGS = -DLIBRARY_DIR=\"@libdir@/xwpe\"
wpe_SOURCES =   we_main.c we_block.c we_unix.c we_e_aus.c \
        we_edit.c we_fl_fkt.c we_fl_unix.c we_hfkt.c \
        we_menue.c we_mouse.c we_opt.c we_wind.c \
        we_prog.c we_progn.c we_debug.c WeString.c \
        WeSyntax.c WeExpArr.c WeLinux.c we_gpm.c 
wpe_LDADD = libxwpe-x11.la libxwpe-term.la
wpe_CPPFLAGS = -DLIBRARY_DIR=\"@libdir@/xwpe\"
we_SOURCES =    we_main.c we_block.c we_unix.c we_e_aus.c \
        we_edit.c we_fl_fkt.c we_fl_unix.c we_hfkt.c \
        we_menue.c we_mouse.c we_opt.c we_wind.c \
        we_prog.c we_progn.c we_debug.c WeString.c \
        WeSyntax.c WeExpArr.c WeLinux.c we_gpm.c
```

The result of the compile is that all c sources are compiled with the define of LIBRARY_DIR, except for `we_main.c` which is compiled without this define.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this difference? What am I doing wrong? Should I not have defined `wpe_CPPFLAGS` but some other flag?

**EDIT 1:** Looking at the Makefile, I noticed that it compiles we_main multiple times! It create `we-we_main.o`, `wpe-we_main.o` and `xwe-we_main.o`. These files are all compiled correctly, but the only one I don't understand is the compilation of `we_main.o` which is compiled without the define. It looks like I am missing a flag that I should have defined. Probably I misunderstand the automake input in Makefile.am. Should I define an extra flag? If so, which one?

**EDIT 2:** Multiple compiles seems a bit wasteful. I am new to autotools, so there might be a better solution. If necessary I will pose a different query about this subject.

Comment: You have multiple compiles for those sources that are listed among the dependencies for multiple targets, where those targets have per-target compilation options.  This ensures that such sources are built for each target according to the options specified for that target.  In your particular case, `Automake`'s rather simplistic test for whether that is necessary is overly conservative, but there are other cases where it is the best available, such as when the necessary options are not known until configure or even build time.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I got it, eventually. Still, seeing the multiple compiles steered me towards using AM_CPPFLAGS in stead of per program flags. Now I have a better understanding of autoools. Apparantly weird stuff can set you on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer due to the observation in `EDIT 1`. First I used `CPPFLAGS = -DLIBRARY_DIR=\"@libdir@/xwpe\".`autoreconf`warned me to better use`AM_CPPFLAGS`, so I did, and that solved the issue.

Additionally, I found I do not need all the program specific `we_CPPFLAGS`, `wpe_CPPFLAGS` and `xwe_CPPFLAGS`, because `AM_CPPFLAGS` adds to all.

So apparantly you only need specific `xxx_CPPFLAGS` if xxx is different from the other programs.

Sorry all to have bothered you. I hope this helps someone else who has the same query.

**Edit 1:** This change also removed the multiple compilations of the same sources. With hindsight, it makes sense: if the `xxx_CPPFLAGS` are specific to one program, then the program `xxx` needs to be separately compiled. If they all have the same flags, this is no longer necessary.